# Изменение содержимого сайта с помощью расширения (Chrome)

Tags: jquery, css, веб-программирование, chrome-extension

Приветствую. Нужно сделать изменение стилей (первоочередно) и содержимого (текста, а-ля локализация) на сайте с помощью расширения Chrome. Как это лучше реализовать? Стили на самом сайте подгружаются через JS уже после загрузки страницы, то есть, насколько я понимаю, просто инжектить CSS не получится.

Пока что колупаю стили, пытался так.
Это манифест:

```
"content_scripts": [{
 "css": ["style.css"],
 "js": ["js/jquery.min.js", "js/content.js"],
 "matches": ["https://site.local/*"]
}],
```

Это content.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("body").css("background-color", "#fff");
});
```

Заранее прошу извинить, если где-то конкретно косячу, первый раз возникла необходимость писать расширение, JS до этого только в кошмарных снах видел, разбираюсь по ходу дела.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, сам уже разобрался. Сделал через добавление своих классов, определенных в style.css, с помощью $().addClass() в content.js.